# Looking for a wire mounted pin header connector

Tags: connector, identification, components, pin-headers

There are connectors on many modern motherboards and peripherals intended to control RGB LEDs. For example, [this one](http://www.scythe-eu.com/en/products/fans/kaze-flex-120-rgb-pwm.html) has a connector like this:

[image]

And it is intended to be connected to the pin headers on the mobo:

[image]

I am looking for such a wire mounted connector like these on the fan, both male and female. The only connectors that I've found so far are ugly jst/molex. Are there connectors like these on the picture?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need wire to board cable assembly like [these](https://www.distrelec.ch/en/cable-wire/cable-assemblies/wire-to-board-cable-assemblies/c/cat-DNAV_PL_1907535?q=*&filter_Buyable=1&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=2&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=3&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=4&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=5&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=6&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=7&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=8&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=10&filter_Number%20of%20Cores=12&sort=Price%3Adesc&filter_Category3=Wire-to-Board%20Cable%20Assemblies&page=2). They do not look bad and come in various sizes. It is important to care about the pitch (distance between adjacent contacts).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for circular male headers and circular female sockets. For whatever reason, the de facto standard for the cheap LED strips is .1" pitch circular pins. I found a couple examples of compatible parts, links below:

Male: [335-10-104-00-160000](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/335-10-104-00-160000/ED10374-ND/2504248)

Female: [316-43-104-41-006000](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/316-43-104-41-006000/ED90565-ND/2639474)